# Data is not being returned from FindFirstDescendant call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, flaui

I am writing a Unit Test and using FlaUI.  I launch an application and then get the main window which is getting the right window but when I try to get a dataGrid from the window it keeps returning null.  The code I am using is below:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "TEST.exe";
info.Arguments = "Unit_Test";
info.UseShellExecute = false;

Application application = Application.Launch(info);

Window mainWindow = application.GetMainWindow(new UIA3Automation());
cf = new ConditionFactory(new UIA3PropertyLibrary());
var dataGrid = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByName("squadronGrid")).AsGrid();
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Just out of curiousity why is this line 'cf = new ConditionFactory(new UIA3PropertyLibrary());' relevant to the example since it is not being used? It just seems suspicious that you happened to use the same name in the lambda expression ( cf ).

Comment: Yes you are right. That line is not needed. But even if I remove it the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found and answer which works.  I removed the following line:

cf = new ConditionFactory(new UIA3PropertyLibrary());

and changed cf.ByName to cf.ByAutomationId.

Thanks for your help.